# C# .NET Core Parser For Retrieving A Dictionary Of Environment Variables In .env File

Tags: .net-core

I have a docker-compose stack for use in `Development` environment that uses a .env file to initialise some environment variables that are used to initialse POCO settings object from user-secrets.

Does .NET Core support parsing a .env file to retrieve a dictionary of environment variable names and values?

Comment: Try this parser library - https://github.com/sprache/Sprache, the code to create .env parser should be simple.

Comment: Many thanks, will take a look at Sprache library :)

Comment: I think there is also a [package for this](https://github.com/tonerdo/dotnet-env)